# Doctrine & Symfony2 join multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I've been struggling with doing a multiple join in DQL.
Here is my code:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT k
         FROM AppBundle:Keyword k
         JOIN k.company c
         JOIN k.entry e
         WHERE c.user = :id
         ORDER BY k.name ASC'
    )->setParameter('id',$user_id);
```

But it gives me "Notice: Undefined index: entry", when executing it.

Here is my keyword entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Keyword
*/
class Keyword
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $user;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function addUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user[] = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 */
public function removeUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user->removeElement($user);
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $company;


/**
 * Add company
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Company $company
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function addCompany(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $company)
{
    $this->company[] = $company;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove company
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Company $company
 */
public function removeCompany(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $company)
{
    $this->company->removeElement($company);
}

/**
 * Get company
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->company;
}

/**
 * Set company
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Company $company
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function setCompany(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $company = null)
{
    $this->company = $company;

    return $this;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $entry;


/**
 * Add entry
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Entry $entry
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function addEntry(\AppBundle\Entity\Entry $entry)
{
    $this->entry[] = $entry;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove entry
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Entry $entry
 */
public function removeEntry(\AppBundle\Entity\Entry $entry)
{
    $this->entry->removeElement($entry);
}

/**
 * Get entry
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getEntry()
{
    return $this->entry;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $ranking;


/**
 * Add ranking
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking
 * @return Keyword
 */
public function addRanking(\AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking)
{
    $this->ranking[] = $ranking;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove ranking
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking
 */
public function removeRanking(\AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking)
{
    $this->ranking->removeElement($ranking);
}

/**
 * Get ranking
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRanking()
{
    return $this->ranking;
}
}
```

And my entry entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Entry
 */
class Entry
{
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $path;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return Entry
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Keyword
 */
private $keyword;


/**
 * Set keyword
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword
 * @return Entry
 */
public function setKeyword(\AppBundle\Entity\Keyword $keyword = null)
{
    $this->keyword = $keyword;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get keyword
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Keyword 
 */
public function getKeyword()
{
    return $this->keyword;
}
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $ranking;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ranking = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add ranking
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking
 * @return Entry
 */
public function addRanking(\AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking)
{
    $this->ranking[] = $ranking;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove ranking
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking
 */
public function removeRanking(\AppBundle\Entity\Ranking $ranking)
{
    $this->ranking->removeElement($ranking);
}

/**
 * Get ranking
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getRanking()
{
    return $this->ranking;
}
}
```

Btw I'm pretty new with symfony and doctrine.
I appreciate all kinds of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide mapping information for each attribute in your model class as well as provide the Entity mapping for the class. Take a look at http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html

Each of your model classes need the @ORM\Entity annotation to tell doctrine it is a mapped entity. So for your case you would have:

```
/**
* Entry
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Entry
{
...
```

Then each attribute you want to be mapped to the database needs an @ORM\Column annotation. For example:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $path;
```

Then you need to create relationship mapping annotations for any relationships between your models (Keyword -> Company, Keyword -> Entry etc), using one of the mappings on here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Once you have all the correct mappings use the command line tool app/console doctrine:schema:update to make sure your model is in sync with your database.

Your DQL seems fine so once you have the correct mappings in place you might have better luck.